# How do I change the scale distance in the Y axis using Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to change the scale of the Y axis from 1 to millions, e.g., (0, 1000, 2000, 3000, ...) transforms in (0, 1, 2, 3, ...). I looked for in lots of matplotlib functions, but I did not find the answer. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know the only way to do this is to scale your data to (0, 1, 2, 3, ...) and then maybe indicate in the axis label that it is "Million ...".

Comment: The simplest way is to just pass two arguments to ```pyplot.yticks```. ```ticks``` gives the locations, ```labels``` is what you want them to be called. https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would be to modify the y-ticks, if you don't want to create new data. Example:

Original:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1e6 *  np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s)

plt.show()
```

[image]

And with modification for y-ticks:

```
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1e6 *  np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s)

ax.set_yticklabels([y/1e6 for y in ax.get_yticks()])  # divide every tick value by 1 million

plt.show()
```

[image]
You could also specify x- or y-axis scale by using consequently `plt.xscale` or `plt.yscale` parameters along with custom [matplotlib.scale.register_scale](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/scale_api.html#matplotlib.scale.register_scale).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply to scale the data itself and label the axis accordingly:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x_data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y_data = [1e6, 2e6, 4e6, 8e6, 16e6]

scale_factor = 1e6
y_data_scaled = [y / scale_factor for y in y_data]

ax.plot(x_data, y_data_scaled)
ax.set_ylabel('My Data (Millions)')
```

[Expected output plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ibmfi.jpg)